# Cannot replace to directory ..../merged/bin with file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, build-error

Im trying to build a docker image and get:

`ERROR: failed to solve: cannot replace to directory /home/user/.local/share/docker/overlay2/4x9idkq31iucxi4u45xhi7wqp/merged/bin with file`

This happens when i am trying to copy.

`COPY --from=builder / /`

The same docker file build and run on my machine but on another machine it doesn't.

My machines docker version: Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
Other machine: Docker version 23.0.6, build ef23cbc

Any idea on how to fix this issue. Thank you.

I pruned the docker system and restarted the docker engine. Tried rebuilding but problem persisted.

EDIT:
Adding a snipper of the dockerfile contents to reproduce the problem:

```html
FROM ubuntu:focal as base
FROM base as builder

# Install dependencies

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:${PATH}"
# RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=set -eux

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

FROM python:3.8.3-slim

RUN mkdir /install
WORKDIR /install
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install build-essential libffi-dev -y && \
    python -m ensurepip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install setuptools wheel && python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip setuptools
ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

COPY --from=builder / /
```

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?  That `COPY` command is trying to overwrite the entire container filesystem, and that's unlikely to work well; you can run into hard-to-debug issues around shared libraries and other sorts of conflicts.

Comment: I have edited my initial post and it now includes a snippet that reproduces the error.

Comment: Trying to copy the entire filesystem from one image stage to another doesn't seem likely to end well: things like the system binaries in `/bin` and the shared libraries in `/usr/lib` will get overwritten with possibly-incompatible things.  What do you want this line to actually do?